# Swift - Core Data Relationship - Album Style

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, entity, relationship

I have been working on establishing a working Core Data relationship for days now. I have made a bit of progress, but nothing substantial, so I am hoping someone much smarter than I would be able to tackle this and help me out.

For a bit of context, I am essentially creating a photo album app. Inside the album, there would be photos, with a caption on each photo. I have structured an entity "**ScannedItem**" that has attributes "savedTitle", "savedText", and "savedImage".

**savedTitle** = The title of the image.

**savedText** = The caption of the image.

**savedImage** = The image itself.

I am not sure how I would go about adding a "ScannedItem" (the entity holding the previous attributes) to my "Album" entity.

For more information, a "ScannedItem", and all of its attributes, may only be in one album, so I believe this would be a 'To-One' relationship.

I have included images of how I have structured my entities and relationships here. [image: Scanned Item Entity]

[image: Album Entity]

Below is my code for saving the "Scanned Item Entity".

```
let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    let saveData = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("ScannedItem", inManagedObjectContext: context)

    let imageRep = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!


    saveData.setValue(textTitle, forKey: "savedTitle")
    saveData.setValue(scannedText, forKey: "savedText")
    saveData.setValue(imageRep, forKey: "savedImage")


    do{
        try context.save()
    }catch{
        print("Failed")
    }
```

How would I go about saving that ScannedItem to an Album? I have been struggling with the code for days and it's nearly driven me insane. Any help would be greatly appreciated. It's time to ask the experts.

**UPDATE**

```
 do{



        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ScannedItem")
        let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)


        let saveAlbum = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Album", inManagedObjectContext: context)

        saveAlbum.setValue(results, forKey: "album")


        let albumRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Album")
        let albumResults = try context.executeFetchRequest(albumRequest)

        if albumResults.count > 0{

        for item in albumResults as! [NSManagedObject]{

            let albumPrint = item.valueForKey("album")

            print("Album Test: " + (albumPrint! as! String))


        }
    }

        if results.count > 0{


            for item in results as! [NSManagedObject]{

                let titleSaved = item.valueForKey("savedTitle")
                let textSaved = item.valueForKey("savedText")
                //let imageSaved = item.valueForKey("savedImage")
                //let titleSaved = item.valueForKey("savedTitle")

                print("Title" + (titleSaved! as! String))
                print("Text" + (textSaved! as! String))
                //print(imageSaved!)



            }


        }


    }catch{
        print("Failed")
    }
```

Now I am receiving an error stating that "the entity Album is not key value coding-compliant for the key "album". I do not know what to do, I have been toying with it for hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `Album`, change `scanItem` to `scanItems` and make it to-many because you can have many items in an album.

Change `albumRelationship` to `album` and set it to to-one.

You need to know or fetch the album you want to add to and then just set:

```
saveData.setValue(album, forKey: "album")
```

Core data will automatically set the other end of the relationship for you.

Comment: I have followed all of your instructions, and updated my question. Thank you for your help. I am losing my mind over this.

Comment: Album doesn't have a relationship to album - it is an album. Album has a set of items. Each item has an album. This is the nature of bi-directional relationships. You should generate managed object subclasses so you can see the properties on them (mogenerator)